# Serenity-BDD report Formatting Issue

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Report h2 and breadcrumb formatting issues on serenity report.

Do we know of a way around this or if this is a Serenity Version issue?

```
    <serenity.version>3.6.12</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>3.6.12</serenity.maven.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>3.6.12</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <mavenfailsafeplugin.version>3.0.0-M5</mavenfailsafeplugin.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
```

[h2 under tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDe8.png)

[dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ftbn.png)

Tried multiple Serenity versions but still getting the same issue.
Expecting report to be formatted as expected.